# How does Bitmap store RGBA raw bitfield?

Tags: bitmap, store, pixel

I am trying to understand how bitmap raw data is stored. I've read quite few articles on bitmap storage, but one article states that the raw bitfield data of a bitmap file will store in a reverse order (ABGR). However, I found another diagram showing ARGB instead. Therefore, I am not sure how should I convert the bitfield into array of RGBA pixel.

Comment: I've left an answer: consider updating the post with more/precise information about exact backing/format which may result in more focused replies.

Comment: I cannot comment for the 'A' component (haven't worked with alpha-containing bitmaps), but the red, green and blue components are definitely stored in BGR order. Also, remember that each row has to end on a 4-byte boundary (add padding if it doesn't).

Comment: Having just checked on Wikipedia, the correct order seems to be BGRA for 32-bit bitmaps.

Answer (score 4):

"It depends"

There are various layouts for both memory and file layouts: the two you mentioned are two common layouts. Generally each A-R-G-B component (or "channel") is 8-bits, but this also "depends".

Wikipedia has some information on the [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_storage): note the variation between the 16, 24 and 32-bit color depths! Also, note that while the articles uses "RGBAX" to talk about the sampling, the data *might be physically laid out as* XAGRB or BGR, etc. "It depends".

Can't compare apples to oranges, and have to make sure to keep the oranges out of the apple basket.

Happy coding.